# Symfony/SonataAdmin Show fields from two entities

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have two entities :

- User that contains login data (with FOSUser),
- and other informations about them (name, first name, date of birth, etc) in another entity called UserInfo.

In SonataAdmin, I want to manage my Users (done) but I need to add fields in the table that are in UserInfo (name, first name...).

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the relationship type, you should be able to just reference `userinfo.firstName`, eg:

```
public function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $show)
{
    $show->add('userinfo.firstName')
         ->add('userinfo.dob');
}
```

Of course, if you have many `userinfo`'s attached to the entity I don't think this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried with an unidirectional relation but it must be bidrectional. 

This was helpful, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There must be existing a relation in between user and userInfo. say OneToOne relation. Then from userInfo entity u will get the user data and will show on the Admin side.
i.e.

```
$subject = $this->getSubject();
$user = $this->subject->getUser();
```

Will give you user, if you want to further perform actions on that user.